# Can I find the surface area for cone by the surface area formula?

Tags: calculus

From section 8.2 in Stewart's calculus, I think I understand the derivation of the surface area formula $\int_{a}^{b} 2 \pi y \sqrt{1 +y'} dx$. It's developed from the surface area of frustums, which is developed from the surface area of a cone, which was found by a sector's area.

So, my question is, can I use that surface area formula to find the surface area of a cone by calculus (rather than how I previously found it by a sector's area) -- or is it logically wrong since I'm already using what I want to find?

I did try it and it did work (using $y=rx/h$) and so on, but I can't help but feel it's circular reasoning. I don't need help in the computational aspects, rather, I need help to the question "is if okay to apply the surface area formula to the cone (when said surface area formula depends on a cone's surface area)" Or, is it okay in this instance since the formulas for cone's surface area were derived differently?

--

Using specifics, the surface area formula seems based upon frustums with surface areas $\pi (r_1 + r_2) \ell$ or $2\pi r \ell$ where $r$ is the average radius $r=\frac{1}{2}(r_1+r_2)$.

Now is it okay to use the line $y=\frac{r}{h}x$ in the surface area formula $$\int_{0}^{h} 2\pi \frac{r}{h}x\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{r}{h}\right)^2} dx $$ to prove a cone's surface area is $\pi r \ell$? Since I find a formula almost identical to what created the surface area formula (like if $r_1=0$), I'm wondering if this method of finding a cone's surface area is logically valid or am I being circular in my reasoning?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Yes you can apply surface area formula to compute surface area of a cone. It is also a surface of rotation. But please also understand that it is a result of rotation of a _line_ at certain angle to the axis of rotation (or you can say a triangle) so $dy/dx$ is fixed.

Comment: @MathLover I've updated my question with some specific formulas in attempts to clarify things.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{h} 2\pi \frac{r}{h}x\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{r}{h}\right)^2} dx$ is absolutely a valid way to establish that surface area of the cone is $\pi r l$.